# sprockets sass partial erb extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, erb, sprockets

I have noticed that with the latest rails and sprockets versions (3.2.1 & 2.2.0) there seems to be a problem when the erb file extension is added to a sass partial.

e.g. if somestylefilename.css.sass is renamed to somestylefilename.css.sass.erb and the file contains a declaration of a sass variable that uses erb, vis:-

$background-colour: <%= '#fff' %>;

all is ok.

However if a sass partial is renamed from say _sharedpartial.css.sass to _sharedpartial.css.sass.erb then the same variable declaration is not recognised.

I am not sure if this is the right forum to report this behaviour or if it is a sass, rails or sprockets problem.

P.S. I know that the asset pipeline targets efficiency through pre-compiled assets, but I am trying to write a theeme controller that is capable of selecting the default colour/layout scheme for a site which will subsequently form the default pre-compiled css asset in production.

Best regards,

John Leake

Comment: What is your question here? I don't see one.

Comment: The issue is most likely related to the contents of your partial, how you're requiring it from the main stylesheet, and the order of 'css', 'sass' and 'erb' in your extension. You should provide a simplified but accurate example of the issue you're having. As @Jey said, you really don't have a question here. This is definitely *not* the place to report bugs related to sass, rails, or sprockets. Each project has it's own issue tracker *(not on SO)*.

Comment: Have you found a way to actually getting it to work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `sass-rails` error, as discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/94).

I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293878/sass-with-erb-wont-compile/14305274#14305274) and found out that the solution is by installing [`sass-rais-path`](https://github.com/quinn/sass_rails_patch).

This gets Rails to work SASS + ERB as expected.

Answer (score -1):

This will sound a bit ridiculous, but have you tried to remove the .erb extension?

Normally you don't have to use it, even if you use erb tags.

Comment: I get an error if I try to use ERB in a .scss file (this is with sass-rails-6.0.0, so it's possible things have changed since 2012): `SassC::SyntaxError at /file
Error: Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= asset_path 'ste"`

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42368807/47185: asset-url() SASS helper