# Sass with erb won't compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline, erb

In Rails, file `file.css.sass.erb`:

```
.class-name
    width: <%= "10px" %>
```

Is throwing the error:

```
Invalid CSS after "": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= "10px" %>"
```

*Isn't it supposed to work?*

### Update 1

Still struggling with it, but I found that if I change it to SCSS syntax (filename and code), still it causes a very similar error.

```
Invalid CSS after " width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= "10px" %>;"
```

Although, if I ***remove*** the `scss` extension, leaving the CSS similar syntax with the filename `file.css.erb`, Rails does compile as expected.

Yet considering I'm forgetting something very obvious, I'm also considering this could be a gem conflict with `sass-rails`, or a bug, or something. *After all, the code is working without SASS extensions.*

### Update 2

Just found other 4 unanswered questions on this same issue on:

1. [scss.erb ruby code not
   executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745129/scss-erb-ruby-code-not-executing)
2. [Assets not being run though the .erb
   preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693226/assets-not-being-run-though-the-erb-preprocessor?rq=1)
3. [Rails erb preprocessing not happening in development
   mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376733/rails-erb-preprocessing-not-happening-in-development-mode?rq=1)
4. [sprockets sass partial erb
   extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268515/sprockets-sass-partial-erb-extension?rq=1).

Some of them ended up working around the problem by changing approaches. The ERB issue on SASS files remained untouched.

Comment: You should add .css to that, and have you tried `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: With `.sass.erb` and `.css.sass.erb` results are the same. Didn't tried precompiling, is it necessary in development environment?

Comment: It's not. What version of rails are you using? The example you gave works fine for me on 3.2.11...

Comment: Rails 3.2.9 here. I'm stumbled, its so simple, just cant figure it out, lol.

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230725/css-in-rails-asset-path-not-processed-by-erb-in-development) they have faced similar problems. Wonder if its a version or gem issue.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use ERB to compile to SASS which then compiles to CSS?! Why not just use SASS? It has [variables](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) already.

Comment: Thanks @iain, but Sass has some limitations that made me consider this approach. You cannot use a complete set of Sass features inside [Control Directives](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#control_directives), for example. Anyway, I would really like to use the `erb` pipeline feature.. isn't it supposed to work?

Comment: Any progress on being able to use *.scss.erb in Rails? Currently there appear to be no updates on said issue out there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is indeed a problem with `sass-rails`, as discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/94).

So [this guy](https://github.com/quinn) wrote [this patch](https://github.com/quinn/sass_rails_patch), which completely solves the problem.

### The Solution

Add to `Gemfile`:

```
gem "sass_rails_patch", "~> 0.0.1"
```

then  run `bundle` and you're good!

Comment: I'm experiencing issues where it makes all the variables in the corresponding .sass.erb file `undefined` when it's imported from another file. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: !Doesn't seem to work for me either (Rails 4.1.0 and sass-rails 4.0.3)

Answer (score 12):

You can use [asset helpers](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-helpers) if the erb is only for referencing assets:

```
background-image: asset-url("rails.png")
```

...instead of...

```
background-image: url("<%= image_path('rails.png') %>");
```